# Rotman's Algebraic Topology Lemma 9.11

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, free-groups, model-categories

This is the Lemma 9.11 of Rotman's "An Introduction to Algebraic Topology".
The topic where I found this simple lemma of homological algebra is the Theorem of Acyclic Models. So we are talking about a category with models.
First of all those are the Lemma and its proof:
[image: Lemma 9.11]

[image: Proof]

This lemma is a fundamental key to the theorem of acyclic models. The advantage of this lemma is to complete the diagram with a natural transformation $\gamma$ using the exactness of the bottom row ONLY on the models $\mathcal{M}$ of the category. The proof uses the analog obvious result for abelian groups (or in general for projective objects).

Keeping in mind the reason for existing of this lemma, I don't understand why we don't take the hypothesis to the first row to be a complex ONLY in models $\mathcal{M}$ exactly as in the second row. In my opinion, the book proves this "stronger" result.

I'm asking this because I found the same Lemma with the same proof also in "Lectures on Algebraic Topology" by Albrecht Dold (11.5 Lemma). I really can't see where is the problem assuming the hypothesis of the first row to be a complex only on models. This seems to me like we want to prove something stronger then what we have but not the "strongest" we can do.

Comment: One can see that the transformation $F→G''$ is zero if and only if it is zero on models. It probably doesn't work the same way for the exactness condition and that's why they didn't "reduce" it to being exact on models as they did for the first row?

Comment: @Idéophage thank you! If the trasformation $F\to G''$ is zero iff is zero on models I totally agree with those Hypothesis! Is this true because $F$ is a free functor and there exist a unique natural transformation (which is zero) extending the zero natural traformation on models?

Comment: Yes, you can see it that way as a consequence of Lemma 9.10, or also the other way around: there is a unique transformation which is zero on models, so if two transformations $τ_1$ and $τ_2$ coincide on models, then $τ_1-τ_2 = 0$ on models and hence everywhere. It's the same thing as with linear maps: if $A$ is an abelian group and $X ⊆ A$ is a generating subset, then a morphism $A→B$ is zero iff it is zero on $X$ ; and two morphisms $A⇉B$ are equal iff they are equal on $X$.

Comment: @Idéophage clear, thank you so much!